# PHP sessions vars are empty after redirect

Tags: session, redirect, shared-hosting

I've written an app on my local machine and everything was perfect until I uploaded the app on a free hosting server. The problem is that all session vars which are set in this piece of code:

```
   if($user) {
        // regenerate session for safety purposes
        //session_regenerate_id(true);
        //set some session vars and redirect
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $user->first_name;
        $_SESSION['admin']      = $user->admin;
        return true;
    }
```

get empty after this redirect (all this code is a part of login system) when I printing them out:

```
       Authentifiacation::login($user, $remember_me);
       Flash::addMessage('Successfully logged in', Flash::SUCCESS);
       // redirect user to the page which he originally requested
       static::redirect('/admin/home/index');
       exit();
```

I just get `Array()` for `print_r($_SESSION)`.

However, they all exist when I print them exactly after setting.
I am using simple MVC framework and everything works great on localhost. I already tried: 
1) add `session_start()` in different parts of the script despite the fact that it is located in front controller index.php
2)`session_regenerate_id()` after setting vars
3)`exit()` after `redirect()`
4) code for setting `register_globals` to off
5) removing .htaccess

Is there any other possible reason?

Comment: Does on your machine turned off the `register_globals` ?

Comment: @vaso123, Yes, I tried to do that in .htaccess file via `php_flag register_globals off` and as found later, it is off by default on my server. And as  I mentioned, everything is perfect on my local machine. The problem only appear on a life server.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using, local and server?

Comment: @EdelmarZiegler, I use php 7.0.15 version on my local machine and php 7.1.16 on the remote server. Do you think this is the reason for the promblem?

Comment: @Kirill Yes, I do. I found your question because I had the same problem, a script that used to work just stopped, and the only thing I've changed was to upgrade from 7.0.x to 7.1.x. After a downgrade back to 7.0 the problem disappeared. In my case I detach the script from to user, terminating the connection but following a long execution (fastcgi_finish_request). I use session to exchange the progress between scripts. Lazy I know, should've use a database... I am note sure if this function is the cause for sessions to break, but downgrading solved.

Comment: @EdelmarZiegler, thanks for your reply.  I just downgraded PHP version to 7.0 but it didn't help. Sessions are still absent. Can it be because I use free hosting?

Comment: @Kirill From what I read when looking for a solution, sessions may not save values when there is a misconfiguration and the save path does not exist or has not appropriated permissions. Also can be due to the drive being out of free space. It is worth noting on the version downgrade, are you sure the server is running the version 7.0. I had to remove+purge the version 7.1 to get it out of my system. Did you check with phpinfo to make sure server is running the 7.0 version?

Comment: @EdelmarZiegler, thanks for help in solving my problem. I just checked the version of php via `phpinfo()` on the server and it shows me php 7.0.20 version. I also checked space on the server's driver, it looks like it has enough space. Lastly, I cannot find session.save_path directory (/storage/ssd2/071/1976071/tmp) in my account's file manager which is specified in phpinfo. It's not present in my public_html as well as in other directories. Can that be the reason?

Comment: In a normal install only user with access to the session save path directory is the user running PHP process, so the fact you cannot see the folder might be a bad sight (if it really does not exist) or a good sign (if it does exist only you don't have access to it - by design). If you have SSH access to the server, the error message from trying to list a non existing path is different from the error for lack of permission.